# Parsing a website's HTML tags in <iframe>

Tags: javascript

Is it possible to parse tags in a html webpage which is shown in an iframe? I have tried to compile the code as follows, but it doesn't work.

```
       <!DOCTYPE html>
       <html>
       <body>

       <iframe id="Frame" src="Url"></iframe>

       <button onclick="myFunction()">Parse it</button>

      <p id="demo"></p>

      <script>
      function myFunction() {
      var x = document.getElementById("Frame").src.getElementByTagName("title");
     document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;
     }
     </script>

     </body>
     </html>
```

Comment: Check out this method https://api.jquery.com/contents/

Comment: `document.getElementById("Frame").contentWindow.document.getElementByTagName("title")`

Comment: @dandavis Could  `document.title` be substituted for `document.getElementsByTagName("ti‌​tle")` ? Missing "s" at "Elements"

Comment: probably. that's another issue w/OP  i forgot to harp on. good eye. what the code will show will not be the document's title, it will be a string version of the DOM object, which is yucky.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can do something like the following. Just remember to change the src of your iframe to the url of the page you are actually loading:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>


<iframe id="Frame" src="sample.html"></iframe>

<button onclick="myFunction()">Parse it</button>

<p id="demo"></p>

<script>

function myFunction() {

var x;         

//get the iframe object
var iframe = document.getElementById('Frame');

//cross browser solution to get the iframe document
//of the iframe
var iframeDocument = iframe.contentDocument || iframe.contentWindow.document;

     //if the document is not undefined
     if (iframeDocument) {

       //do something with the frames dom

       //get the content of the title tag from the iframe
       x = iframeDocument.getElementsByTagName("title")[0].innerHTML;

        }    

              document.getElementById("demo").innerHTML = x;    

}

</script>

</body>
</html>
```

**Note:** This solution will not work on websites that do not allow cross origin loading in iframes. If you were to add the url `http://www.google.com` to the src of the iframe for example it would display the following error in the developer console.

```
Load denied by X-Frame-Options: https://www.google.com/?gws_rd=ssl does not permit cross-origin framing.
```

This is another error you may receive for the same reason. I recieved this error by trying it on by own website(bytewarestudios.com).

```
Error: Permission denied to access property "document"
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your solution! Does it work also if I change the src in the iframe into a URL, such as www.google.com?

Comment: @jiten2015 No it will not work on google.com, You will get the result that I ammended to my solution at the bottom. A lot of times the iframe will not load the url because the server will not allow the loading of the page in an iframe that is from a different domain. In other words the web page you are trying to load is not in the same folder as your web page.

Comment: Got it. Thank you again for your detailed explanation!

Comment: @jiten2015 No problem, I am glad I could help.