# How do I use the HTML IFRAME element to embed content?

Tags: html, iframe

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>My favorite app</title>
</head>
<body>

<iframe src="https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36047483/parsing-a-websites- 
html-tags-in-iframe"></iframe>

<div class="title">My App</div>
<div class="app">
    <div class="image"><img src="images/app.png" alt="this is a 
    screenshot" class="image"></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

i tried to use iframe tag but it doesn't work and a blank section is appeared as that image.
[the blank section that appears to me in the browsers.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CmorD.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

That's because Stack Overflow disallows use inside a frame by setting `X-Frame-Options` to `sameorigin`... 
So only is allowed as iframe inside Stack Overflow itself, not from your code.

Long version:
When your browser try to access that URL from Stack Overflow, Stack Overflow returns some headers, one of them is `X-Frame-Options: sameorigin`, that instructs your browser to disallow to display that URL inside an IFrame, so your browser refuse to do it.
Its a SO server config (you can't do anything about it).

Comment: your answer is too short to understand can you clarify it.

Answer (score -1):

The Stack Overflow page you reference in the `src` attribute is not displayed in the `iframe` element because the Stack Overflow site implements an iframe blocking policy. In order to do this, it uses the **`X-Frame-Options`**. (See also [how to block website from loading in iframe?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19843085/6002174).)

You can check whether a site implements this policy by inspecting its HTTP headers. For example, in Firefox, press `F12` to open the inspection tools, then go to **Network**, select one of the objects that were sent over HTTP and look at the headers (or filter the headers for e.g. "x-frame"). Below is what this looks like for [the URL you tested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36047483/parsing-a-websites-html-tags-in-iframe):

[image]

Notice **x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN** in the lower right part of the screenshot. With `x-frame-options: SAMEORIGIN` or `x-frame-options: DENY` set on the server side, you will not be able to load pages from that site inside an `iframe` or a `frame`.

For more background, see [X-Frame-Options – How to Combat Clickjacking](https://www.keycdn.com/blog/x-frame-options/), which also explains other values that can be used in the `x-frame-options` header.

If you want to test with a webpage from a server that does not block loading in iframes, try for example https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Tomcat.

Comment: that's a very good answer that is exactly what i need thanks for you