# Unable to parse elements from a website that contains tabular data (iframe)

Tags: python, html, selenium, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

We are trying to parse `href` attributes from the DOM of a [job website](https://www.artemiskliniken.de/Karriere/%C3%84rzte/). We want to get an `href` for each job.

We usually use CSS paths and pass those to Selenium's [`find_elements_by_css`](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html) method.

Unfortunately, we've noticed that the browser plugin [SelectorGadget](https://selectorgadget.com/) had trouble providing us with a CSS path. We proceeded to use a CSS path using Google Chrome (ctrl+shift+c). Chrome could extract a path, but neither Selenium nor [BeautifulSoup](https://beautiful-soup-4.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) can work with those paths.

After many failed attempts to extract the elements using different classes and tags, we believe something is entirely wrong with either our approach or the website. We hypothesize that the desired elements are impossible to parse by Selenium and BeautifulSoup for whatever reason? Could the `iframe` tags in the DOM be a source of error (see this [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36047483/parsing-a-websites-html-tags-in-iframe))? What makes the parsing fail here, and is there a way to get around this problem? A website-related problem source would also explain why the SelectorGadget was unable to get a path in the first place. Our conclusion would be to use regular expressions to extract the `href` attributes that we need. This would only be a last resort solution.

For German-speakers, please note that there is a spelling error in the target elements: `<div class="stellenagebot">`. Please do not let yourself get confused by those (as we did).

No luck with BeautifulSoup:

```
import re
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup


url = 'https://www.artemiskliniken.de/Karriere/%C3%84rzte/'

page = requests.get(url)

soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')

print(soup.prettify())
# Out: ...

#<div class="col-md-4 wow fadeInUp">
# <div class="stellenagebot">
#  <h3>
#   Facharzt (m/w/d) für Augenheilkunde in Voll- oder Teilzeit
#  </h3>
#  <h4>
#   Erfurt
#  </h4>
#  <a class="btn btn-default" href="/Stellenangebot/Facharzt_Augenheilkunde_Erfurt/">
#   Mehr
#  </a>
# </div>
#</div>
#<div class="col-md-4 wow fadeInUp">
# <div class="stellenagebot">
#  <h3>
#   Facharzt (m/w/d) für Augenheilkunde in Voll- oder Teilzeit
#  </h3>
#  <h4>
#   Eschwege
#  </h4>
#  <a class="btn btn-default" href="/Stellenangebot/Facharzt_Augenheilkunde_Eschwege/">
#   Mehr
#  </a>
# </div>
#</div>

# ...

print(soup.find_all('.stellenagebot'))
# Out: []

print(soup.find_all(string=re.compile("Stellenangebot")))
# ['Stellenangebote Facharzt für Augenheilkunde und Karrierewege für Ärzte', '<h3>Zur Verst&auml;rkung unseres Teams suchen wir:</h3>\n\n<p class="hyphenate" lang="de">&nbsp;</p>\n\n<div id=\'jobauflistung\' class=\'row\'><div class=\'col-md-4 wow  fadeInUp\'><div class="stellenagebot">\n<h3>Facharzt (m/w/d) für Augenheilkunde in Voll- oder Teilzeit</h3>\n\n<h4>Aachen</h4>\n<a class="btn btn-default" href="/Stellenangebot/Facharzt_Augenheilkunde_Aachen/">Mehr</a></div></div><div class=\'col-md-4 wow  fadeInUp\'><div class="stellenagebot">\n<h3>Facharzt (m/w/d) fü
# ...
# ></div>\n</div>\n</div>\n</div>\n</footer>\n</div><!-- AUF ALLEN SEITEN IN DEN BODY-TAG EINFÜGEN ']

print(len(soup.find_all(string=re.compile("Stellenangebot"))))
# Out: 2
```

Also no luck with Selenium:

```
from selenium import webdriver

from job_scraper.configuration import CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION, ROOT_PATH, \
    CHROME_OPTIONS


driver = webdriver.Chrome(
    ROOT_PATH / f'assets/chrome_drivers/{CHROMEDRIVER_VERSION}',
    options=CHROME_OPTIONS
)
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get(url)
driver.find_elements_by_css_selector('.stellenagebot')
# Out: []
```

Comment: if element is in `iframe` then it is treated as separated page and you have to load it. `Selenium` has even `switch_to.frame(...)` to load content in `iframe`. `BeatifulSoup` will not parse elements in `iframe` because it is not part of current page and you have to get url from `iframe` and load it with `requests`

Comment: when I check page in web browser then I see `stellenagebot` only in HTML in comment `<!-- .... -->` so `BeautifulSoup` and `Selenium` doesn't treat it as HTML but normal string in comment. So it may have to get text from `comment` and parse it separatelly.

Comment: this page uses JavaScript in table - so I don't see any `href` in displayed table because URLs are hidden somewhere in JavaScript. I see `href` only in HTML in comment.

Comment: Thank you for that background info! @furas

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The element you are searching is inside `comments` . you need to have this tag information first and then convert into string and then parse again in order to get the value.

```
from bs4 import Comment
import requests

url = 'https://www.artemiskliniken.de/Karriere/%C3%84rzte/'
page = requests.get(url)
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.text, 'html.parser')
#Capture Comments element
comments = soup.find_all(text=lambda text:isinstance(text, Comment))
Newsoup = BeautifulSoup(''.join(comments), 'html.parser')
for item in Newsoup.select('[href*="Stellenangebot"]'):
    print(item['href'])
```

**Output:**

```
/Stellenangebot/Facharzt_Augenheilkunde_Aachen/
/Stellenangebot/Facharzt_Augenheilkunde_Bad_Berleburg/
/Stellenangebot/Facharzt_Augenheilkunde_Bad_Hersfeld/
/Stellenangebot/Weiterbildungsarzt_Augenheilkunde_Beckum/
/Stellenangebot/Facharzt_Augenheilkunde_Beckum/
/Stellenangebot/Weiterbildungsarzt_Augenheilkunde_Dieburg/
/Stellenangebot/Facharzt_Augenheilkunde_Dieburg /
/Stellenangebot/Facharzt_Augenheilkunde_Dillenburg/
/Stellenangebot/Facharzt_Augenheilkunde_Duisburg/
/Stellenangebot/Facharzt_Augenheilkunde_Erfurt/
/Stellenangebot/Facharzt_Augenheilkunde_Eschwege/
/Stellenangebot/Facharzt_Augenheilkunde_Frankfurt/
/Stellenangebot/Facharzt_Augenheilkunde_Helmstedt/
/Stellenangebot/Weiterbildungsarzt_Augenheilkunde_Heppenheim/
/Stellenangebot/Facharzt_Augenheilkunde_Herborn/
/Stellenangebot/Facharzt_Augenheilkunde_Hoyerswerda/
/Stellenangebot/Facharzt_Augenheilkunde_Koeln/
/Stellenangebot/Facharzt_Anaesthesie/
/Stellenangebot/Weiterbildungsarzt_Augenheilkunde_Leverkusen/
/Stellenangebot/Facharzt_Augenheilkunde_Limburg/
/Stellenangebot/Facharzt_Augenheilkunde_Mainz/
/Stellenangebot/Facharzt_Augenheilkunde_Marburg/
/Stellenangebot/Facharzt_Augenheilkunde_Melsungen/
/Stellenangebot/Facharzt_Augenheilkunde_Moers/
/Stellenangebot/Weiterbildungsarzt_Augenheilkunde_Moers/
/Stellenangebot/Facharzt_Augenheilkunde_Moerfelden/
/Stellenangebot/Facharzt_Augenheilkunde_Muehlhausen/
/Stellenangebot/Facharzt_Augenheilkunde_Isenburg/
/Stellenangebot/Weiterbildungsarzt_Augenheilkunde_Oberhausen/
/Stellenangebot/Facharzt_Augenheilkunde_Oberhausen/
/Stellenangebot/Facharzt_Augenheilkunde_Obertshausen/
/Stellenangebot/Facharzt_Augenheilkunde_Oberursel/
/Stellenangebot/Facharzt_Augenheilkunde_Offenbach/
/Stellenangebot/Weiterbildungsarzt_Augenheilkunde_Offenbach/
/Stellenangebot/Facharzt_Augenheilkunde_Ruesselsheim/
/Stellenangebot/Facharzt_Augenheilkunde_Salzkotten/
/Stellenangebot/Facharzt_Augenheilkunde_Wetzlar/
/Stellenangebot/Facharzt_Augenheilkunde_Wiesbaden/
```